# Node js - Synchronous execution of functions through loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-side-scripting

I have a code like the following

```
function getData()
{
   for(var i=0; i<someLength; i++)
   {
       if(i===0)
       {
          response = callApi(someValue[i]);
       }
       else if(i===1)
       {
          responseInsert = callWebSocket(response, someValue[i]);
       }       
   }
}
function callApi(insertData)
{
  axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://localhost:1130/services/request',
  data: insertData,
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/xml;charset=utf-8' }
  }).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
  retVal = true;
  return retVal;
  }).catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);    
 });
}
```

In this, response is needed for callWebsocket function with a array's value, that should be achieved through loop. But callWebSocket function gets called before the response comes due to the asynchronous nature of node js. But I have a use case to use server side scripting and I choose node js. Any help to execute the functions synchronously with the loop in place will save me.

Comment: Have `callApi` return a `Promise` and then `await` it

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code? - @CertainPerformance

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what `callApi` is currently

Comment: Updated - Using axios, I think it already returns a promise.- @CertainPerformance

Comment: wouldnt a simple callback work for you?

var myCallback = function(data) {
  console.log('got data: '+data);
};

var usingItNow = function(callback) {
  callback('get it?');
};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the callApi method a bit. Try this:

```
async function getData()
{
   for(var i=0; i<someLength; i++)
   {
       if(i===0)
       {
          response = await callApi(someValue[i]);
       }
       else if(i===1)
       {
          responseInsert = callWebSocket(response, someValue[i]);
       }       
   }
}
function callApi(insertData)
{
  return axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://localhost:1130/services/request',
  data: insertData,
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/xml;charset=utf-8' }
  });
}
```